# Remote file upload with PHP does something wrong with the file

Tags: php, ftp

Sorry if I missed a question similar to this one here but I couldn't find answer to this. So I am uploading files from a remote server to my server using the FTP with PHP. Here is my code.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['remote'])) {
        $source = $_POST['remote'];
        $filename = time() . ".apk";
        $server = "my_server_address";
        $user_name = "username";
        $password = "password";
        try {
            if(ftp_connect($server)) {
                $connection = ftp_connect($server);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Could not connect to FTP server");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        ftp_login($connection, $user_name, $password);
        ftp_put($connection, $filename, $source, FTP_ASCII);
        }
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="remote">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Everything goes fine. I connect to my server successfully and remote file is uploaded successfully too. But when I check the file on my server after the upload completes, it breaks (corrupts).

Please note that I am uploading the APK files of Android apps (with .apk extension) with this method.

Any solution to this? Please help.

Comment: @JulioSoares: I have updated the question with complete code, please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.apk files are executable code, so you would want to use `FTP_BINARY` instead of `FTP_ASCII`.

Comment: Hmm, let me give a try

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked :)

Comment: Glad that I could help you.